# How to scroll down in table with selenium python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

check the scrrenshot please 
https://www.screencast.com/t/dNgVy1xWON

https://www.screencast.com/t/6P0MUQoO

```
PAGE = 1
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 4

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    print("Scrolling to page %s" % PAGE)

    # Scroll down to bottom
    # if time.time() // 9 % 5 == 0:
    #     print("window scrolling to bottom")
    #     break

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break

    last_height = new_height
    PAGE += 1
```

i need the scroll down but this stay not doing anything

Comment: What is your exact usecase? What are you trying to automate?

Comment: i need to scroll down only

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/7pTf27bAir0Y

Comment: You are already scrolling down through `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")` what else are you looking for?